# How can we move shopware6 plugin into the cloud?

Tags: shopware

I have developed the plugin in shopware6 and I  want to move it to the cloude, How can we do that and manage the versions of plugins as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Within the cloud version you need an [APP](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/extensions/apps-concept).

Answer (score 1):

You have to migrate your plugin code to app code. The effort depends on the complexity of your plugin. I.e. a Theme is pretty easy to port from plugin to app system.
But the more backend logic you have the harder it gets. Because apps are more limited then plugins for self-hosted shopware in nature.

You will find some first approaches in the official docs https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps